# in youtube API 3 user authentication required or registering the app by the developer is enough?

Tags: api, youtube

i want to develop an android app using youtube API 3.

It is necessary that the user who will be using the app has to login with his/her gmail credentials to actually view a video?

Or just registering the app here https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application is fine and the user watching the video or using the app need not login to his/her gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

> It is necessary that the user who will be using the app has to login with his/her gmail credentials to actually view a video?

No. Authentication via OAuth is only necessary if your application requires access to "private user data". Simply viewing a video does not meet those requirements.

More details here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication